# Why is the error "can not import name 'path'" coming in django latest version

Tags: python, django

I am a beginner at Django. When I am giving python `manage.py runserver` or any python command then the terminal output is:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, path
ImportError: cannot import name 'path'
```

Comment: You are probably not using the latest version of Django.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be:

```
from django.urls import include, path
```

Comment: sorry, I somehow edited your answer and I cannot revert :(